# Joomla code not seeming to work

Tags: php, joomla

I have a PHP if statement on my joomla template that does not seem to be working. What I am wanting is that if you are NOT on the homepage (default page) to load the following code, otherwise, DON'T load the code. However, its loading the code giving me the unwanted look. If statement is below:

```
<?php /*see if we are on the homepage, if not load article tags and modules*/ 
$menu = &JSite::getMenu();
if (JRequest::getInt('Itemid') != $menu->getDefault()) : ?>
  ...my code...
<?php endif; ?>
```

If you visit [www.testingtesting1.info/jutwynne](http://www.testingtesting1.info/jutwynne/) you will see the code being loaded - using firebug or whatever dev tool you prefer. the code that is being loaded is:

```
<div id="article" class="float-left">
<div id="additional-lins" class"float-right">
```

The above tags are empty when on the homepage and again, when on the homepage these tags should not be loading at all.

I've asked around everywhere, joomla.org and experts-exchange with no answers (literately no answers). This is my last hope.

Comment: echo out the values of `JRequest::getInt('Itemid')` and `$menu->getDefault()`

Comment: You mean add an echo or remove - if its remove there is no echo. Additionally, why would I echo them? I don't need them to print to screen.

Comment: The problem is that the if statement isn't being triggered; which means that one of those two variables doesn't have the right value. If you echo them out, you can see what the values are, and figure out why it's not working. You can take them back out again when you're done debugging.

Comment: Tried it. Got a blank screen.

Comment: That generally means that there's an issue with the PHP syntax; could you edit your question so it includes the `echo` calls you tried?

Comment: 'code'<p>Itemid: <?php echo JRequest::getInt('Itemid'); ?></p>           <p>menu: <?php $menu = &JSite::getMenu(); echo $menu->getDefault(); ?></p>'code' Itemid returns 101 but menu does not return anything

Comment: Then the issue is with the $menu->getDefault() call. Does Lodder's answer help? Otherwise, you'll have to look through the documentation to figure out why that might not be returning anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the code you put in your question is for Joomla 1.5

The following is used for Joomla 2.5/3.x

```
<?php
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$menu = $app->getMenu();
if ($menu->getActive() !== $menu->getDefault()) {
       //echo your code 
}
?>
```

Comment: oh you're on 3.0, should point these things out before hand ;) I'll look into it

Comment: hmm well looking at the docs, the code should work. 
http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_determine_if_the_user_is_viewing_the_front_page

Comment: @andrewsi - have I put my `!` symbol in the correct place? having a mind blank at the moment :/

Comment: I had to make a change to your code you !== to !=. but this worked